# Condition for a quadrilateral to be tangential

Tags: geometry

Define a quadrilateral to be tangential iff all four of its internal angle bisectors meet a a single point. Prove the following:

> A quadrilateral is tangential **if and only if** three of of its internal angle bisectors meet at a single point.

I'm having trouble proving this. I managed to do it for cyclic quadrilaterals, but not for tangential ones. I need complete proof for sake of completeness, I'm always struggling with simple things that just seem too obvious not to be true.

I tried to find it on Google, but all results were about the $a+c=b+d$ condition (since it's much more important and useful anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Start thinking with a single angle, i.e. one point and two lines. Any point on the angle bisector will have the same distance from either line, and hence can be the center of a circle tangent to both lines. Conversely, any center of a circle touching both lines will have its center on that angle bisector.

Now take a second adjacent angle, i.e. two points and three lines. Their angle bisectors will intersect in a single point which is the center of the unique incircle of the triangle, i.e. the only circle touching all three lines.

Now if you have a third adjacent angle, and all three angle bisectors meet in a single point, then there is a unique circle which has the same distance to **all four** lines involved. Hence the whole quadrilateral will be tangent to a circle with that common point as its center. That center has to lie on the angle bisector of the fourth angle as well.